# How to achieve EditText inputType: DONE button one keyboard + wrapping to next line

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-inputtype

I am trying to achieve exact inputType with no succes.

The criteria are following

- DONE button is visible on the keyboard
- when text is longer than 1 line, its wrapped to the next line
- max height e.g 3 lines

Any idea how to get it?

Comment: The keyboard is its own app.  It can decide what to put in that button, and you can't force any generic keyboard to do anything.  At best you can give it some hints.  But most keyboards will just default to a newline in a multiline field.

Answer (score 0):

***if you want to use DONE Button you can't use multi lines just single line***

```
 <EditText
       android:imeOptions="actionDone" // for adding DONE Button
       android:inputType="textMultiLine" // for using multi lines , DONE Button will be disappeared. Use “text” instead.
       android:maxLines="3" // 3 lines maximum 
       />
```

To control DONE Button

```
 editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
            if (i == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE){
                // What do you want to do when clicking on Done Button
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```